# Tracking user path in Google maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, plot, polyline

I've been trying to plot the user path from one point to other after he starts his travel. Am using Google maps iOS SDK and GMSPolyLine to plot the path after the user starts his travel.

Am tracking the travel using `locationManager:didUpdateLocation` and plotting the line after the user updates his location. Am not able to get the paths plotted properly as it happens in google maps when we search for paths from one point to other. I've added screenshots for the difference happening.

My app:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h1wjedgcszc685g/IMG_6555.png?dl=0

The above is my app's screenshot and you can note that the turns are not plotted properly

The Output required:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/poqaeadh1g93h6u/IMG_6648.png?dl=0

Can anyone point me towards the best practice to plot a neat path similar to google maps?

Answer (score 0):

This happen because your location is not update continuously and when it update polyline is draw straight between two point so you have to do one think when you get the next location you have called [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=false&mode=driving&origin=50.7262771,-1.2319503&destination=51.1439274,0.8763692999999999&alternatives=true) api.

When you called this api you get the route array between two point you passed from that you get your best route(possible first route). From that route dictionary extract the **overview_polyline** object. **overview_polyline** object is decoded latitude and longitude array of the location point between your two point.

when you convert it via following methods then you have exact polyline which you want

There are two methods to decode polyline

> First method

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark - decode polyline
// these function is given by client
-(void) decodePoly:(NSString *)encoded Color:(UIColor *)color
{
    GMSMutablePath *path = [[GMSMutablePath alloc] init];
    //    NSString *encoded=@"g|vfEmo{gMz@h@PJNFRJNDXHJ@b@FZ@F?L?XAVCr@Kj@Ut@]zAi@HETE^IVELCPANAhCYHAHCHCHCHEh@i@";

    NSUInteger index = 0, len = encoded.length;
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < (len - 2)) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            //            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:((double) lat / 1E5) longitude:((double) lng / 1E5)];
        [path addCoordinate:loc.coordinate];
    }
    GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    // Add the polyline to the map.
    polyline.strokeColor = color;
    polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0f;
    polyline.map = [self getGoogleMap];
}
```

> Second methods

```
GMSPolyline *polyline =[GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:[GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:"your encoded string"]];
        // Add the polyline to the map.
        polyline.strokeColor = color;
        polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0f;
        polyline.map = [self getGoogleMap];
```

May this thing help you.

Comment: in some case app crashed in decodePolyLine method at characterAtIndex *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds' if in while loop of decodePolyLine method i changes the while (index < len) to while (index < len-2 ) it doesn't crash @chirag shah

Comment: @amitgupta thank you for this suggestion. i update my answer.

Comment: Second method is working fine  but 1st method crashes in some cases so u can not  change this while loop because in some case in work for len-1, len-2 based on different -2 address . SO my suggestion is that use 2nd method instead of 1st one to avoid crash. @chirag shah