# Can Google Map SDK track someone location iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, tracking

My App is an app for taxi driver and the user who call it.

I need to let the user track the taxi driver location and draw the route on the map to make him know where is he?.

I searched a lot for a way to implement this functionality 
and I found [PubNub Tracking](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-05-05-getting-started-ios-location-tracking-and-streaming-w-swift-programming-language/) which is a good way for tracking.

But I was thinking if the GoogleMapSDK can do that?

anyone try to do something smiler to this functionality using googleMapSDK?

Thanks.

Comment: No google maps cant do that

Comment: @ZellB. how do you know that?

Comment: Because of Google ! Google it

Comment: @ZellB. sure I did that before I asked the question! and there were no good results, but I didn't find any result about the inability of googleMaps

Comment: Btw you can easily implement your own tracking service using Firebase

Comment: @ZellB. Firebase!!! HOW ?!
It's an Analytics tool

Comment: Firebase is BaaS. Again google it please

Comment: Check this SO question [29826387](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826387/tracking-user-path-in-google-maps-ios-sdk?rq=1) and [18422826](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422826/how-to-track-a-users-location-and-display-the-path-travelled-using-google-maps?rq=1) if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that this is not allowed for Standard plan users. According to the ToS paragraph 10.4 (c):

> No asset-tracking unless you have purchased the applicable Maps for Work license. Unless you have purchased an applicable Maps for Work license that expressly permits you to do so, you will not use the Service or Content for commercial asset-tracking or in Maps API Implementations whose primary purpose is to assess vehicle insurance risks.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions